# Can I tell Jackson to conditionally serialize a private instance variable based on differently-typed method?

Tags: java, jackson, type-conversion

To the best of my understanding, Jackson will

- serialize a public instance variable to the variable name

  `public List<String> myStrings = new ArrayList<>();`

  serializes to

  `{ 'myStrings' : [ ... ] }`
- serialize a private instance variable to the variable name if it has a public getter named `getVariable()`:

  ```
  private List<String> myStrings = new ArrayList<>();
  public List<String> getMyStrings() { return myStrings; }
  ```

  serializes similar to

  `{ 'myStrings' : [ ... ] }`

---

However, what I am trying to achieve is to serialize it to a String (instead of array of Strings) based on another method, but keep the JSON key (based on `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` suppressing the original accessor in some cases

```
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)

    private boolean firstStringOnly = true;
    private List<String> myStrings = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<String> getMyStrings() { return firstStringOnly ? null: myStrings; }
    public String getFirstString() { return firstStringOnly ? myStrings.get(0) : null; }
```

Desired JSON serialization:

- For `firstStringOnly==true`: `{ 'myStrings' : 'first_String' }` (using `getFirstString()`)
- For `firstStringOnly==false`: `{ 'myStrings' : [ ... ] }` (using `getMyStrings()`)

Is this possible to do? I'm specifically looking to avoid using custom serializers, and do this via annotations only.

You can assume a reasonably recent version of Jackson and Java 8.

Just to re-iterate, the question constraints are:

## * NO custom serializer

## * Both use cases produce the same JSON key

Comment: I'm aware that the method has a bug if the array is null or empty. This was a minimal example :P

Comment: In case people wonder what mushrooms this spec is on, this is to maintain backwards compatibility with old API version which expects a string instead of list of strings; the boolean is actually `isOldAPIVersion`.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Sorry, i have misread your initial question. I assume you want to keep both of the typed getters. Would this work for you?

```
public class TestClass {

  private boolean firstStringOnly = true;
  private List<String> myStrings = new ArrayList<>();

  @JsonIgnore
  public boolean isFirstStringOnly() {
    return firstStringOnly;
  }

  public void setFirstStringOnly(boolean firstStringOnly) {
    this.firstStringOnly = firstStringOnly;
  }

  @JsonIgnore
  public List<String> getMyStrings() {
    return firstStringOnly ? null : myStrings;
  }

  @JsonIgnore
  public String getFirstString() { return firstStringOnly ? myStrings.get(0) : null; }

  @JsonProperty("myStrings")
  public Object getMyStringsForSerialization() {
    return firstStringOnly ? getFirstString() : getMyStrings();
  }

  public void setMyStrings(List<String> myStrings) {
    this.myStrings = myStrings;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generalize getMyStrings() method and make it return Object. And inside check the flag and return first value or all values. Here is my sample

```
public class tst {
private static class YourObject {

    private boolean firstStringOnly;
    private List<String> myStrings = new ArrayList<>();

    public YourObject(boolean firstStringOnly) {
        this.firstStringOnly = firstStringOnly;
        this.myStrings.add("str1");
        this.myStrings.add("str2");
    }
    public Object getMyStrings(){
        return firstStringOnly ? myStrings.get(0) : myStrings;
    }

}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(new YourObject(true)));
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(new YourObject(false)));
    }
}
```

The output is

```
{"myStrings":"str1"}
{"myStrings":["str1","str2"]}
```

Comment: This does work but how would I invoke the code in main() **if I don't have a custom serializer** (I know exactly how to write custom serializers, though admittedly your code is a bit more elegant than what I would have written for that)

Comment: Why do you think you need custom serializer? What lib do you use to map your class to json? My main is simply for testing. The idea is to change in your code only `List<String> getMyStrings()` to `Object getMyStrings()`, its logic a little bit  and remove other unused getters

Comment: I see what you mean. So the `writeValueAsString` would just get called by normal Jackson mechanisms, didn't realize that. +1 for now, I will try this out and accept if this works. My main concern is will this somehow break de-serialization on the other end.

Comment: That's interesting question. I think everything will be ok with deserialazation until version mismatch occurs. When sender will generate json with list and the other side will expect single string.

Comment: that's the root cause of this whole excercize. I have V2. server and V2 clients (that generate/expect a list); and a legacy V1. client that expects a single string. V1 will decerialize fine as it has old class with "String" variable, getter and Setter. V2, i'm less certain about.

Comment: I am intrigued, let me know the results after testing :)